# get values from table1 and insert in to table2 in jsp

Tags: sql, oracle, jsp

I want to take values from table1 and insert it into table2 (oracle, jsp) with auto inserted time (default current time). However it is returning an error. Here is my code

`String insert_history = "insert into table1 values (select firstname, name, lastname, birth_d  from table2 where iduser='"+u_id+"')"`

table1 has ( firstname, name, lastname, birth_d, insert_date) ---

However I don't know how to insert date in default when inserted data. I would be glad If you could help.

Comment: insert into t1 (c1, c2, <not time>) select ca, cb from t2

Comment: The other variant with values is `insert into t1 (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('John', 'Doe')`

Answer (score 2):

If you use `VALUES`, don't use `SELECT` (and vice versa).

So:

```
insert into table1 (firstname, name, lastname, birth, insert_date) 
  select firstname, name, lastname, birth_d, sysdate
  from table2
  where ...
```

Note that you should **always** name all columns you're inserting values into. Yes, it requires more typing, but will save you from future errors.